# Check if a string is empty in action script, similar to String.Empty in .net

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript

Is there a static property in Action similar to that in the String object in .net to check if a string is empty, that is String.Empty.

Thanks

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
if(string) 
{
    // String isn't null and has a length > 0
}
else
{
   // String is null or has a 0 length
}
```

This works because the string is coerced to a boolean value using [these rules](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87.html):

String -> Boolean = "false if the value is null or the empty string ( "" ); true otherwise."

Comment: Me too :S, It is emportant not to compare against "" so as not to create unnecessary strings

Comment: This works indeed. Look at the paragraph **casting to boolean** here http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/learn/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html#WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f87

Comment: Bellissimo! The most elegant solution :)

Answer (score 5):

The following will catch all of these:

1. NULL
2. empty string
3. whitespace only string

---

```
import mx.utils.StringUtil;

var str:String

if(!StringUtil.trim(str)){
   ...
}
```

Comment: It does not answer exactly the question, but is useful nonthelesss.

Answer (score 4):

You can use `length` but that is a normal property not a static one. You can find here all the properties of of the class [String](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html#propertySummary). If length is `0` the string is empty. So you can do your tests as follows if you want to distinguish between a `null` String and an empty one:

```
if (!myString) {
   // string is null
} else if (!myString.length) {
   // string is empty
} else {
   // string is not empty
}
```

Or you can use Richie_W's solution if you don't need to distinguish between empty and null strings.

Comment: Thanks, actually I need only to check if empty or null